# Training model on the same data for too long make its predictions unusable even for training data

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I encountered strange situation with long training process. The model after some time of training becomes very bad even for training data set! How can it be? I'm not sure if it's somehow relates to overfitting. 
Training it for short period of time makes it pretty good, but continuing training turns it into completely broken stuff.
I checked model weights there is no NaNs or 0s.

Comment: Are you using any learning rate decay strategies?

Comment: @Ash, I'm using default learning rate that is in tensorflow.js. I don't use any regularizers and etc. My network is for Reinforcement Learning(Q-Learning) and has 3 layers: 16 input neurons, 15 hidden neurons and 4 output neurons. At the beginning my network explores game maze with exploration rate 100% which gradually decreases to 0.

Comment: It can be due to overfitting as you are training for very large epoch.